# Accessing number of parameters in a closure in Swift

Tags: swift, overloading

Suppose I have a function:

```
func test(closure: (closureArgs: Double ...) -> Double){
    //some logic
}
```

Then later, I call it with:

```
test({$0 + $1 + $2 + $3})
```

Is it possible to get the number of `closureArgs` provided within `test`? The goal would be to do overloading. For example, `test` could include some code like:

```
func test(closure: (closureArgs: Double ...) -> Double){
    //somehow get access to number of arguments in closureArgs within the closure that was passed.
}
```

To clarify - I mean I need to access closureArgs's length INSIDE `test` but OUTSIDE `closure`

Comment: Do you need access to the count from inside the closure, or outside the closure but inside test?

Comment: Outside the closure but inside test.

Comment: It sounds like what you're wanting is to have test take a single closure argument.  Each closure takes a fixed number of arguments, but test doesn't know how many?  What you're declaring here is that test takes a closure that takes a variable number of arguments, if you see the distinction.

Comment: That sounds about right. The goal is to avoid a bunch of overloading functions ie `func test(closure: Double -> Double)` then `func test(closure: (Double,Double) -> Double` and so on. Instead it would be awesome to write it as one function then just switch the logic inside `test` based on number of arguments in the closure

Comment: The count of the double array is determined by the number of parameters used in calling the closure from inside the `test` function. you can only call the closure from test if you know the count? I don't see the problem..

Comment: What is the kind of logic you want to implement based on the count? Is it "If I have two parameters, I want the closure to add them; if I have three parameters I want the closure to multiply them?" Or is it, "I want the closure to perform the same function regardless of the count, but I want to handle the result differently?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to get the number of closureArgs provided within test?

#### The Short Answer

No.

#### Slightly Longer Answer

No, it is not.  Here's why:

The function is taking a closure as it's argument that by definition takes a variadic number of arguments.  There's no possible way for someone calling the function to designate how many arguments the closure should take ahead of time. For example, if I were to call your function, it might look like this:

```
test() { (closureArgs: Double...) -> Double in
    var n: Double = 0
    for i in closureArgs {
        n += i
    }
    return n
}
```

As you'll notice, I don't define the number of arguments anywhere because the number of arguments is only specified when the closure is called.  Then the number can be determined inside, or possibly returned.

Basically, the closure is called within test, so only you the caller know how many arguments it takes.  Anyone consuming this function has no control over it.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I can think of is to have the closure return a tuple that contains the number of arguments and a function that gives the answer, like this:

```
func test(c: (Double...) -> (Int, (Double...) -> Double)) {
    let (argCount, function): (Int, (Double...) -> Double) = { c($0) }()

    switch argCount {
        // do something with function here
    }
}

func sum(a: Double...) -> (Int, ((Double...) -> Double)) { 
    return (a.count, { reduce(a, 0, +) })
}
```

Something like that might work, but I'm not in a place where I can test it.

Edit: I'm trying to test this now, and it's close, but it doesn't work yet...

Edit: Okay, this works, but maybe not in the way that you want...

```
func test(c: (Int, Double)) {
    let (argCount, result) = c

    switch argCount {
        case 2:
            println("2 args were passed")
            println("The result was \(result)")
        default:
            println("nothing")
    }
}

func sum(a: Double...) -> (Int, Double) { 
    return (a.count, reduce(a, 0, +))
}
```

Now `test(sum(2, 4))` will print that the number of arguments was `2` and the result was `6`.

The thing is, when you are passing a closure that already has arguments supplied (and it needs arguments to know how to calculate the count) then you're closure function already evaluates to a result. So have the closure return the number of arguments that it used to calculate the result along with the result. Then in `test` you can work with both the number of arguments and the result.

I don't know...it's hard to know exactly what you are after because I'm not sure what kind of logic you need to implement once you know the number of arguments...

Edit: Sorry I keep going on and on, but it seems like you know how many arguments are going to be included when you call test, right? I mean, in your example you supplied 4 arguments:

```
test({$0 + $1 + $2 + $3})
```

(Although, you really need to rewrite that as:

```
test({ return $0[0] + $0[1] + $0[2] + $0[3] })
```

...cuz remember, variadic parameters are passed as an array...)

So if you know how many arguments are going to be in the closure when you pass it to test, just include the number of arguments as a parameter in test, like this:

```
func test(count: Int, closure: (Double...) -> Double) {

    switch count {
        case 1:
            // do what you want if there is only one argument
        case 2:
            // do what you want if there are two arguments...etc.
    }
}
```

Now when you call test, you just pass the number of arguments as an `Int`:

```
test(4, { return $0[0] + $0[1] + $0[2] + $0[3] })
```

In other words, *you always know how many arguments you are passing to the closure when you pass it*. If you want `test` to know, just include that as a parameter.

Comment: Hmm yes, you can pass the number of variables into the function. That's not a terrible hack but not ideal. Technically Logan has the right answer so I will have to mark his as correct but you definitely get an upvote for your answer!

Comment: Thanks for the great question...that one makes ya think :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer goes back to how Swift passes arguments to varargs functions, which is as an array.  Generally speaking, the function definition:

```
func takesVarArgs(args: Double...)
```

Is syntactic sugar, providing for simpler invocation, for the declaration:

```
func takesVarArgs(args:[Double])
```

So, in your case, your closure will be invoked as:

```
func test(closure: (closureArgs:[Double]) -> Double)) -> Double
```

Then, within your closure you could get the number of arguments with:

```
closureArgs.count
```

Comment: Yes, I know I can get closureArgs.count within the closure. I was wondering if its possible to get the count within test (the parent function)